# Which part I have to know to write eclipse's plugin for analyse Java source code?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, code-analysis, static-analysis

I want to write some plugin to analysis Java source code. Which part of eclipse's plugin I have to know? I know this is a stupid question, but I really don't know where I have to start and I don't have too much time. I am not an actual programmer, I am a computer repair technician. So I just can write plugin (I love it) in spare time.

I am really grateful if someone give me a few pointers.

Comment: You are being very ambitious.  If you don't know how to program, you will not be able to master Eclipse APIs. First learn to crawl before you learn to walk.  :)  I would suggest that you learn Java first, and then try your hand at writing a plugin.

Comment: Oh, thanks for help. Actually, I know Java core about a year. I know awt, swing, multi-threading... And now I want to write a plugin in eclipse, I also write first plugin follow some tutorials. Can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg: please give me some suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't mean to be snarky above.  So, I'd first recommend getting to understand the Eclipse architecture, plugin model and APIs.  Here is an old, but still relevant tutorial:

http://eclipsepluginsite.com/#

It doesn't go into JDT at all, but does give you an idea about Eclipse plugins in general.  So, once you understand that tutorial, you can move on to JDT:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html

Comment: Good luck and feel free to ask more questions here.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to master quite a lot -- the `Builder` API to hook into the incremental build process and get notified when files change, the `IResource` type hierarchy to get to the source files, the Java AST classes (there's a big bunch of those), some quirks concerning type bindings, etc. There is no simple pointer to give.

Comment: How can I get the content of the classes in a given project? Java AST? What are they? Can I reuse them? Thanks!